# Xml Parsing on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xml

I have checked lots of tutorials on xml parsing in iOS ..
but most of them have already set the xml response from the server in a clear understandable line by line format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<people> <person>
<firstName>James</firstName> <lastName>Franklin</lastName>
</person>
<person>
<firstName>Snidely</firstName>
<lastName>Wilsonn</lastName>
</person>
<person>
<firstName>Dudley</firstName>
<lastName>Doright</lastName>
</person> </people>
```

Now seeing this.. it is pretty easy to follow what tags you have to filter and extract data from ..

**But now when i am doing this . (like this in my app)**

```
  NSError *error;
    NSData *linkData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"someURL"] options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error]
        NSString *stringData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:linkData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@" Data /n/n/n %@",stringData);
```

It is coming like this in console :

```
Data /n/n/n {"entries":[{"id":"37504814","title":"Live Blog: Patrik Schumacher","created":"2012-02-09 23:43:00","updated":"2012-02-10 03:34:05","user_id":"15084","entry_type":"20","location":null,"portfolio_id":null,"arc_name":"Lian Chikako Chang","parent_image":"xyz2sb7y9n4mtvbb.jpg","link":"http:live-blog-patrik-schumacher","quote":null,"content":" \n<p>\n\tHi Archinect!<\/p>\n<p>\n\tPatrik Schumacher, partner at Zaha Hadid Architects and founding director at the AA Design Research Lab, is in Piper tonight for a lecture on \"Parametric Order: 21st century architectural order.\"<\/p>\n<p>\n\t<img alt=\"\" src=\"http
```

NOw this is JSON and XML both .. but there are thousands of lines more after it /...and i am not able to understand it as it is...any way to get it in the proper formatted format like the above given XML.??

ALSO one more question : Is the XML parser best for parsing or should i do it with other projects for xml parsing on github?.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will format xml the xml for you to make it more readable.

http://xmltoolbox.appspot.com/

Comment: +1 to all of you for your help... now i want to know one thing...there is a content part in the response that has been formatted with different tags and other stuff ... like /n so if i want to show the content part in a text view...how to do the proper removal such that there is no such words come up like /n yet there is a new line

Answer (score 1):

1. What you get is JSON  string with HTML tags embedded. (Is it intended?. or the response is corrupt).
2. You can't parse the HTML with XML Parser.
3. NSXMLParser is a SAX parser. It is good for large amount of data.

Comment: +1 to all of you for your help... now i want to know one thing...there is a content part in the response that has been formatted with different tags and other stuff ... like /n so if i want to show the content part in a text view...how to do the proper removal such that there is no such words come up like /n yet there is a new line

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to understand your question. But you need to take look at following tutorials. You really need it :

[How To Choose the Best XML Parser for your iPhone Project](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project)

[How to Read and Write XML Documents with GDataXML](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml)

[How to Translate Text with Google Translate and JSON on the iPhone](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1448/how-to-translate-text-with-google-translate-and-json-on-the-iphone)

It will really help you.

Comment: +1 to all of you for your help... now i want to know one thing...there is a content part in the response that has been formatted with different tags and other stuff ... like /n so if i want to show the content part in a text view...how to do the proper removal such that there is no such words come up like /n yet there is a new line

Answer (score 1):

- Your response content is in `JSON` format.And in turn it contains `HTML` data for the key : **`content`**.

  `NSXmlParser` is both `DOM` and `SAX` parser. But the selection of the parser depends upon various factors.
   You can refer to [this blog](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) for how to select a XML Parser.

Comment: +1 to all of you for your help... now i want to know one thing...there is a content part in the response that has been formatted with different tags and other stuff ... like /n so if i want to show the content part in a text view...how to do the proper removal such that there is no such words come up like /n yet there is a new line

Comment: The value of the content consists of HTML data. It would be better to use UIWebView, which would display the text along with proper formatting. But if you don't want the HTML formatting, then ask the server team, not to send the HTML content.